# How to get the list of "friends" of a suspended Twitter account

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to make an app to help people recover the list of "friends" they used to follow after their Twitter account has been suspended.

The `GET /friends/list` endpoint allows you to look up this up, but when I try it for suspended accounts I get a `Not authorized` error (using `python-twitter`).

Is it possible to look this up in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Nothing like this can be accessed via API about suspended accounts.